# Multiple payloads in MVC core rest api

Tags: rest, asp.net-core-mvc, payload, asp.net-core-routing

I am developing a rest api on .Net core 2.2 following MVC pattern.

I have a controller with a post method like this...

```
// POST: api/Todo
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> PostTodoItem(string param, [FromBody] TodoItem item)
{
    // some work... 

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTodoItem), new { id = item.Id }, item);
}
```

And it works fine.

The customer asked to have an api on the same route, but the Json body could have 2 different structures, bearing the same data on different schemas.

I considered using

```
PostTodoItem(string param, [FromBody] Object item)
{
// TryCast item to one of the possible POCO classes then work with the correct one. 
}
```

Do you know a better way, maybe with some advanced routing and filtering option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really possible nor desirable. Pretty much the core tenant of REST is a URI uniquely represents a particular resource. If you've got a URI like `POST /todo`, then the post body should be a "todo" and it should create a new "todo" based on that. Here, that is a `TodoItem`, so that is *all* that should ever be posted.

REST aside, this just won't work. When your action is activated, the modelbinder attempts to bind the post body to the param(s) that the action accepts. It basically just news up whatever type the param is, and then attempts to find something from the post body to bind to the various properties on that type. This is an intentionally simplistic description of what's happening; the important part is that the type of the param informs how the post body is bound. If you bind to an `object` (which has no members) or even a base type, then the only members of the post body that will be bound are those that are present on that type, not derived types thereof. Anything that cannot be bound is discarded.

Long and short, you need a unique route for each type of thing you're working with. Under the hood, you can share or otherwise reuse code by factoring out common functionality into private methods, employing inheritance, etc., but you need a distinct action and route to handle each case.

Comment: you are right, and you inspired me to study better some parts of MVC. Unfortunatly the customer insisted in having multiple payloads. for now I created a "superclass" that can hold all formats (one branch of the JSon payload is connected to different parent objects in the different formats), then I map this superclass to a proper one. Maybe there are better solutions (I would be happy to learn them), but considering that I cannot force the customer to use a proper standard that's the best I could do in the allotted time.